Comparison of temperature matrix - statistical result not practical reality?
I have the following issue: I want to compare thermal pictures (data is present as a big Matrix/ each Pixel one value) in python and decide weather they are different. What statistical approaches are relevant? How do I proceed to find a good test? What are other approaches to compare matrixes/ pictures in python?
I have a few data sets and know that some of these data should be seen by the test as different and some as similar. I tried paired t-Test, Wilcoxon-test with different region of interests in the picture. The result is always that the images are signficantly different. This is not the practical reality. Some pictures are practically not different.
Is there a different test did not consider/ a way to modify the test? Are statistical tests not appropriate for this problem? Other algorithms? Any tips how I can proceed?

repost of previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78769753/how-do-i-compare-two-big-temperature-matrix-datasets-and-classify-the-difference

welcome again. please review [tour], [ask], [mre]. you can [edit] your question.

This is a fundamental question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Bear in mind that statistical significance is something different than practical significance. Instead of looking at t-tests, etc., just define a metric to quantify the difference between images, and then look at the value of the metric. This is so-called "effect size" analysis. Stats.SE can say more about that.

@RobertDodier try writing [stats.se] to get such a link: [stats.se]

new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78805957/temperature-matrix-as-phash
